# GCC LD variable section size

Tags: gcc, linker, g++, embedded, ld

After reading [this Embedded Gurus article](http://embeddedgurus.com/state-space/2014/02/are-we-shooting-ourselves-in-the-foot-with-stack-overflow/) about stack overflow, I'm interested in reversing the order of static RAM and the stack in an embedded (bare-metal ARM) project.  See the following diagram:

[image: stack ordering diagram]

**Current:** All static RAM data is placed into the overall RAM section.  The "Start of Stack" address is fixed at the highest RAM address and provided as a linker-defined symbol.

**Reversed:** This would be simple if the "Static Variables" section were of fixed size but the size changes as variables are added/removed.  What I would like to do is place all the static RAM data into the end of RAM and then determine where the stack should start based on the size of the static RAM data.  That "Start of Stack" address would then be provided as a linker-defined symbol.

Is there a way to have a section of variable size to hold static RAM data at the end of the overall RAM section?  If not, how could this reversal be implemented without requiring a fixed-size section for static RAM data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the gcc linker descriptors allow you to pin the end of a section and have it grow down.   I think green hills allowed this, and Kiel doesn't.

BUT, you probably don't really want to do what you want to do.   You should be sizing the stack deliberately and not be relying on the hardware to solve your problem, particularly if it really matters (I.e. Safety critical).

Also, it's not guaranteed your mcu will actually hard fault when it accesses outside of physical RAM.  That's implementation dependent.

Comment: The goal here is to size the stack "as large as possible" while enforcing a deliberate minimum size.  While fixing the stack to the size determined for the project would be acceptable, the unused RAM might as well be allocated for the stack.